# Running Windows processes in separate cores

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, multi-core

I have an AMD FX-6200 (3.8GHz, six cores) and I would like to optimize it in this way:

- Core 1: Used only by key Windows processes, e.g. explorer.exe, svchost.exe, rundll32.exe, etc.
- Core 2: Used only by secondary Windows processes that will often be started/stopped, e.g. cmd.exe/powershell.exe, taskmgr.exe/procexp.exe, and so on.
- Core 3: Used only by CPU-heavy user applications that aren't optimized for multiple cores.
- Core 4: Used by user applications. (default)
- Core 5: Used by user applications. (default)
- Core 6: Used by user applications. (default)

One of the reasons I want to do this is that Windows usually distributes the CPU load evenly over all processors, but when you run a CPU-heavy  single-thread process it often runs significantly slower than it could simply because 20% of the core it runs on is already occupied by other processes, and Windows seems incapable of moving those processes to other cores at runtime effectively.

I know how to set processor affinity in Process Explorer, but a) this isn't permanent, b) you can't set default values for unknown processes, and c) it really isn't an option for the myriad of Windows' background processes. I'm basically looking for a solution where the OS automatically uses core 1 and user applications by default use cores 4/5/6, with me being able to specify in advance for certain processes to be moved to cores 2 respectively 3 instead. Is something like this possible?

I'm running 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter, but it's the Windows 7 kernel so solutions for Windows 7 might also apply.

---

Edit: There is a Microsoft tool called [IIS](http://www.iis.net/) that is described as a web server but seems to have capabilities related to setting processor affinity for pools of applications. Does anyone have experience with this IIS and can tell me whether (and how) it can be used for my purposes?

Comment: try this 3rd party application: https://bitsum.com/processlasso/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built in solution. As far as I know, there isn't even a permanent 3rd party solution. At anytime, a program may specify a processor affinity. So even if the OS does move a process, the process can move itself back.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

> c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C start /affinity 1 mstsc.exe

Comment: Absolutely correct. But why you need `cmd.exe ...`. Wouldn't be  `start /affinity 1 [any program]` enough?

Comment: I gave you an example start it whatever you like